# Protocol used between a RADIUS client and a computer?

Tags: networking, radius, 802.1, protocol

I can't find documentation about the protocol used when a computer wants to reach a network with 802.1x.

RADIUS client (switch, access point) use UDP/1812-1813 to communicate with RADIUS server.
How does computer (at this point with no IP) and RADIUS client communicate?
Is there some ARP traffic? Is local link used ?

I tried to look for this information on Google and used Wireshark, I really have no clue at the moment.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK they use [EAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) initiated by the client transmitting intermittent EAP-Requests.

Comment: Which OSI layer is it?

Comment: 802.1x uses EAP over LAN (EAP over IEEE 802) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X

Comment: @KonradGajewski : That is the point I think.

Comment: Wrong manip : I pressed enter. @KonradGajewski : That is the point I think. I am looking for the Layer 3 protocol in use. For what I can see, EAP is somehow SSL / TLS like, not a layer 3 protocol. Although, i thought it was just some layer 7 thing, which it is not, thanks Reaces and Hyppy : I have read these wiki again, asking myself if EAP was a layer 3 protocol. If I understand properly, EAPOL is the layer 3 protocol, and is using MAC address and MAC multicast to send messages.